# SQL Query find the highest earners for each department with ID, Name and department in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am trying to write a query which gives the highest earner (Salary+Bonus) and name of the employee and ID for each department.

I have the following table named Tab1:

| ID | Emp | Dep | Salary | Bonus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mary | X | 50 |  |
| 2 | Adam | Z | 60 | 15 |
| 3 | Brad | X | 55 | 20 |
| 4 | Fred | Y | 80 | 30 |
| 5 | Irene | Y | 90 |  |
| 6 | Alan | Z | 100 | 10 |

I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT Dep, MAX(Salary) 
FROM Tab1
GROUP BY Dep
```

But this just give me the salary without bonus. I also want to get ID and Emp as a query result.

So the expected result would be:

| ID | Emp | Dep | Max_total_salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Brad | X | 75 |
| 4 | Fred | Y | 110 |
| 6 | Alan | Z | 110 |

I would appreciate any suggestion you have!

Comment: you mean the salary and bonus summed up together ?

Comment: You [asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71856833/sql-query-to-find-the-highest-earner-for-each-department-with-their-name) earlier, the answer is the same. If you don't understand the linked duplicates then you explain in your question what about them you don't understand. If you think your question isn't a duplicate, then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71856833/edit) your **original** question to explain why it isn't a duplicate; don't repost it.

Comment: I checked the links, but still couldn't find any case would fit my situation.

Comment: The answer is still the same, @squillman . `MAX` isn't what they want/need.

Comment: @larnu Yeah, sorry.  Skimmed over that the other was a dupe....  Saw the error and figured it was deleted because the syntax was fixed here.

Comment: I didn't mean to duplicate it. I tried to ask my question with more clear explanation. The reason it's not the same with the link is, I need to sum two columns up and then use that column in the query

Comment: The logic is *identical* @complog , you are just ordering by `Salary` plus `Bonus`, instead of just `Salary`. I would *assume* you know how to use the plus operator.